# How to reference to primary key?

Tags: sql

```
create database [PostaShpejte]

use PostaShpejte

create table Posta
(
    ID_Posta int not null Primary Key,
    Emri varchar(50)not null,
    Qyteti varchar(15) not null,
)

create table Dergesa
(
    ID_Dergesa int IDENTITY(1,1) not null  Primary Key,
    Emri_Dergeses varchar(30) not null,
    Pershkrimi varchar(100),
    Qmimi int not null,
    Statusi varchar(30) not null,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Statusi CHECK (Statusi='E regjistruar' or Statusi='E nisur' or Statusi='Ne depo' or Statusi='E refuzuar' or Statusi='E derguar'),
)

create table Menaxhon
(
    ID_Dergesa int not null references Dergesa (ID_Dergesa),
    ID_Posta int not null references Posta(ID_Posta),
    Primary Key(ID_Dergesa,ID_Posta),
)

--drop table TelBleresi

create table TelBleresi
(
    ID_Tel_Bleresi int not null,
    --ID_Bleresi int not null,
    NumriTel int not null Unique,
    Primary Key(ID_Tel_Bleresi),
)

--drop table Bleresi

create table Bleresi 
(
    ID_Bleresi int not null,
    ID_Tel_Bleresi int not null,
    Emri varchar(20) not null,
    Mbiemri varchar(20) not null,
    Shteti varchar(20) not null,
    Qyteti varchar(20) not null,
    Rruga varchar(50) not null,
    ZIPKodi int not null,

    FOREIGN KEY(ID_Tel_Bleresi) references TelBleresi(ID_Tel_Bleresi),
    Primary Key (ID_Bleresi , ID_Tel_Bleresi),
)

create table Dergohet
(
    ID_Dergesa int not null,
    ID_Bleresi int not null,
    Data_e_regj date not null,
    Data_e_mbrritjes date not null,
    ----------------PROBLEM HERE---------------------------
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Dergesa) references Dergesa(ID_Dergesa),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_Bleresi) references **Bleresi**(ID_Bleresi),
    *Error: There are no primary or candidate key to table Bleresi ....*
    ---------------------------------------------------------

    PRIMARY KEY (ID_Dergesa,ID_Bleresi),
)
```

Comment: In which SQL dialect?

Answer (score 1):

Bleresi has a compound primary key `(ID_Bleresi, ID_Tel_Bleresi)`, so you need to reference all columns. That means adding ID_Tel_Bleresi to Dergohet.

```
create table Dergohet(
  ID_Dergesa int not null,
  ID_Bleresi int not null,
  ID_Tel_Bleresi int not null,  -- add this column
  Data_e_regj date not null,
  Data_e_mbrritjes date not null,

  FOREIGN KEY (ID_Dergesa) references Dergesa(ID_Dergesa),
  -- Reference the full compound key
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_Bleresi, ID_Tel_Bleresi) references Bleresi(ID_Bleresi, ID_Tel_Bleresi),

  PRIMARY KEY (ID_Dergesa,ID_Bleresi),
)
```

While they have some uses, compound primary keys are annoying as they create a proliferation of foreign key columns and complicate indexing. Some of yours seem unnecessary: Bleresi already has a ID_Bleresi, is that not unique?

In general, I'd recommend using simple *big* integer (2 billion creeps up on you surprisingly fast) auto incrementing primary keys. If you need to guarantee other uniquenesses, make a [unique index](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_create_unique_index.asp).

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (ID_Bleresi) references Bleresi(ID_Bleresi, ID_Tel_Bleresi)` -- doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The error say that ID_Bleresi is not the primary key on Bleresi table and for that can't be a foreign key. The primary key is:

```
Primary Key (ID_Bleresi , ID_Tel_Bleresi)
```

If ID_Bleresi is not a unique column, I recommend that in the table, you create a new unique column that is the primary key. In case it is, it would be best to set  ID_Bleresi as the unique primary key

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed up